# Too many rendering options available when backing out of a drill down

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

SSRS - In Report Viewer we allow users to output to PDF and Excel.  However, when they drill down to a linked report then hit the blue back button to get to the parent report, they are then able to export to all of the standard SSRS export options; XML, CSV, MHTML, TIFF, etc.
In SQL Profiler I see the queries from for both reports, but when I hit the back button I don’t see anything, so I’m assuming everything is handled in report viewer.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why is this a problem? If there is no security or performance risk, I would simply ignore this new found capability.
Many times we create 'problems' demanding a solution when there is none.

Comment: The easy answer is "the product manager wants it." The other answer is; our reports have complicated graphs, sub reports, etc.  We're using SSRS in a more complicated manner than I have ever seen.  Considering the nature of the output, we don't want to data blowing up or otherwise being misrepresented in formats we haven't QA'd.

Comment: If you need tight control of the interface, then you'll need to build your own interface. It's not that hard. Instead of placing a report viewer in your site, use the web services to get the reports and pass them on to clients. Search on "SSRS URL access" for some ideas. This does mean that you'll need to build the interface to collect parameters, though.